# Index a large number of fields with unit in solr

Tags: solr

I have a large number of fields, which I need to use as facets. So I need to index these fields in SOLR.

Now, these fields support multiple units, and the user may enter value for it in any supported unit. For instance, "distance" is a field with supported units "km, miles, m". User might enter a distance as 10m or 5km

For sorting a field, I would like to convert all its values to a base unit, and sort on the converted values. However, for general display as well as filtering results, I need the raw/unconverted values.

What would be the best indexing approach in this case? I am trying to avoid indexing both converted and unconverted values due to the large number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to index both values. In your `schema.xml`, configure the field with the converted base values as indexed and stored, then configure a second field for the raw display values to be stored but not indexed. As you have to convert the user input to your base unit for sorting anyway, you can use it too for searching on the base unit field.

If you use the parameter `fl` to control the fields given back to you from Solr, be sure to include the field with the raw values.